# Get text between 2nd and 3rd delimiter in a string - Java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, substring

I have a string like this  -  tom|harry|john|elizabeth|hopkin|wayne

I would like to extract the value john and wayne from this string and store in variables. How can I do that in jquery or javascript?

Comment: Why exactly `john` and why exactly `wayne`? What is the logic?

Comment: @VisioN - no logic, there could be any value instead of this, just that these are separated by pipes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know which "index" john and wayne is, you can use `split()` to make it an array and get it from an array with index.

```
var str = "tom|harry|john|elizabeth|hopkin|wayne"
var arr = str.split("|");
var third = arr[2],
    last = arr[arr.length-1];
```

Comment: perfect, worked very well. Also, would you have idea if using a reg ex would be fast than this or not and if yes, would you know what would be the reg ex for this.